# Angular how to listen to data (video) and execute something, when it is loaded

Tags: angular, typescript

I am displaying video in my angular page and I want to set the currentTime property to my video and start playing it at specific time.

In javascript you can achive something like that with this example:

```
document.getElementById("video").addEventListener(
  "loadedmetadata",
  (e) => {
    e.target.currentTime = 50;
  },
  false
);
```

I have trouble setting the startTime in my Angular application
My HTML code is:

```
<video
        id="lecture-video"
        controls
        #video
        (timeupdate)="onVideoChange($event)"
      >
        <source [src]="videoUrl" />
      </video>
```

Typescript:

```
  @ViewChild('video') video!: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit():void {
     console.log(this.videoTest.nativeElement);
     console.log(this.videoTest.nativeElement.currentTime);
}
```

In stackblitz it works, but in my project it doesn't. If i put

```
setTimeout(()=>{
console.log(this.videoTest.nativeElement.currentTime)
}, 3000)
```

then it works. So main question is: **How can I wait or add listener which will execute when the video is loaded?**

**Stackblitz example:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z5dzvg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Thanks to everyone for help!

Answer (score 0):

You got only one mistake, instead of using `ViewChildern` you should use `ViewChild`.

```
import { AfterViewInit, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('video') video!: ElementRef;
```

Then you will get your video element in your console.

---

***-------------------Updated----------------------------***

Add implement AfterViewInit in your component class

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit { ... }
```

Use ViewChild to get the element

```
@ViewChild('video') video: ElementRef;
```

Use video variable to get the element

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   console.log('video', this.video.nativeElement);
}
```

Comment: In Stackblitz example it works, but in my project i still get error in my console.log.. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement'), because video is not loaded yet.. if i add setTimeout(()=>{console.log(this.video.nativeElement)},3000) it works.. How can I wait untill video is loaded?

Comment: yes you could do that or try ngAfterContentInit() hook. Ref: https://angular.io/api/core/AfterContentInit

Comment: still undefined. I need some listener to my video component i guess

Comment: updated the code, and tested it on my local environment as well.

Comment: This doesn't work in my project. In stackblitz it works, but not in my project.. it still isn't loaded in ngafterview intit.. If i use settimeout((){},2000) thhen it is loaded..

Comment: Did you implement it in your component class? Also, can you post some of your actual code?

Comment: I posted a part of my actual code in question. I implemented it.. I know that it should work, but as i said many times before, i need somehow listen to my viewchild and execute code when it is loaded.. this is the issue. because with settimeout it works..

Comment: You current code is not helping to understand what issue you are facing exactly. You could use setTimeout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246544/discussion-between-devz-and-iftikharyk).